# Parsing variable from delimited file

Tags: rust

I have some file content which delimited by pipe `|` symbol. Named, `important.txt`.

```
1|130|80|120|110|E
2|290|420|90|70|B
3|100|220|30|80|C
```

Then, I use Rust `BufReader::split` to read its content.

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::Prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("important.txt");
    let display = path.display();

    //Open read-only
    let file = match File::open(&path) {
        Err(why) => panic!("can't open {}: {}", display,
                           Error::description(why)),
        Ok(file) => file,
    }

    //Read each line
    let reader = BufReader::new(&file);
    for vars in reader.split(b'|') {
        println!("{:?}\n", vars.unwrap());
    }
}
```

The problem is, `vars.unwrap()` would return bytes instead of string.

```
[49]
[49, 51, 48]
[56, 48]
[49, 50, 48]
[49, 49, 48]
[69, 10, 50]
[50, 57, 48]
[52, 50, 48]
[57, 48]
[55, 48]
[66, 10, 51]
[49, 48, 48]
[50, 50, 48]
[51, 48]
[56, 48]
[67, 10]
```

Do you have any ideas how to parse this delimited file into variable in Rust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your data is line-based, you can use [`BufRead::lines`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines):

```
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let input = r#"1|130|80|120|110|E
2|290|420|90|70|B
3|100|220|30|80|C
"#;

    let reader = BufReader::new(input.as_bytes());

    for line in reader.lines() {
        for value in line.unwrap().split('|') {
            println!("{}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you an iterator over `Strings` for each line in the input. You then use [`str::split`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split) to get the pieces.

Alternatively, you can take the `&[u8]` you already have and make a string from it with [`str::from_utf8`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html):

```
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let input = r#"1|130|80|120|110|E
2|290|420|90|70|B
3|100|220|30|80|C
"#;

    let reader = BufReader::new(input.as_bytes());

    for vars in reader.split(b'|') {
        let bytes = vars.unwrap();
        let s = str::from_utf8(&bytes).unwrap();
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

You may also want to look into the [csv](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/csv/) crate if you are reading structured data like a CSV that just happens to be pipe-delimited.

Comment: got it. Thank you very much.